# REGEX Replacing

Tags: javascript, regex

How could I use regex to replace something like this:
`abc-123456789`
to something different?
The `ABC` is always the same, but the `123456789` changes.

I know that a regex like `/abc-/` will select the first part, but I can't find out how to select the numbers.

Comment: replace abc-123456789 to "something different." @MarkLinus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = "abc-12345";
var replacement = "REPLACEMENT";
var t = s.replace(/abc-[0-9]+/, replacement);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
str.replace(/abc-\d+/gi,"something");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mystring.replace("/abc/-[0-9]{9}", "Something else");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.replace(/(abc-)([0-9]+)/gi, function(str, group1, group2) {
    return group1 + someFunction(group2)
}
```

`group1` is what is int the first parentheses; `group2` — what is in the second. The function gets the string and these two groups as its arguments. You can rewrite `group2` and return new string with this part changed.

Comment: More general, but too complex here.